# Limit AssumeRole by IAM User Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-sts, aws-policies

I'm trying to create a trust relationship on a role I created in AWS, but I want it to only be accepted by an IAM User Group, instead of creating another account that has limited access to resources.

Right now, the JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::[AWS-AccountID]:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::[AWS-AccountID]:group/IAMCentral"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But, with this condition, my user can't switch role. If I delete the condition, then he can use it, but all the others outside this specific IAM Group are also allowed to switch to this role.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

> What can I do?

Nothing. User group **can't be** a [principle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-principalarn). Instead you should attach IAM policy to the group, not the other way around.

Comment: And the reason IAM groups can't be principals is "because [IAM] groups relate to permissions, not authentication, and principals are authenticated IAM entities" as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_groups.html).